# Testing MySQL adaptive_hash_index option

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-8.0

We recently migrated our application to an entirely new infrastructure, going from a single server managing everything to a kubernetes cluster and dedicated database server running on AWS RDS. On Thursday, we had a planned spike in traffic due to marketing campaigns being sent, and during the middle of this peak we experienced a huge slow down in response times. Upon initial investigations, we discovered it was because the database was running at 100% CPU usage, and all queries were taking a long time to return (expected given the CPU usage)

We've never seen this behaviour before, so we're trying to determine if we've simply hit the max capacity of the server for that workload, or if we can improve this. During our research, we came across a few posts discussing the `adaptive_hash_index` option. We came across this because when we analysed the data from RDS, we saw a lot of `btr_search` waits.

[image]

The posts we saw suggested that in some applications, it may be beneficial to disable the `adaptive_hash_index` option. What we need to know though, is would this be beneficial given what we're seeing here, and more importantly how can we test that it has actually done anything and made a positive difference?

We don't usually have the level of traffic we saw, and under our usual workload we have absolutely no performance issue that we're aware of. The queries that were taking a long time to respond at peak, don't usually take more than < 50-100ms to return.

Could anyone shed some light on what might be another potential issue if not the hash index, and how we may go about testing it if we disable? I can provide further metrics as requested.

**Slow queries**

As requested, I've got a couple of examples of some slow queries. These are two of the more common queries that appear during our slow period

```sql
SELECT
  table_a.id
, table_a.name
FROM `table_a`
INNER JOIN `table_b` ON `table_a`.`id` = `table_b`.`product_id`
INNER JOIN `table_c` ON `table_b`.`brochure_id` = `table_c`.`id`
WHERE `table_c`.`id` = 215
AND `table_a`.`enabled` = TRUE
AND `table_a`.`table_d_id` = 20
AND `table_a`.`ref` IS NULL
ORDER BY table_a.name;
```

This query took just under 2 minutes to return 10,541 rows. Running this query now when the system isn't under load, it takes ~250ms. Below is the explain plan

```
+-------------+---------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| select_type | table   | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                              | key                                        | key_len | ref                    | rows  | filtered | extra                                        |
+=============+=========+============+========+============================================================================================================================================================+============================================+=========+========================+=======+==========+==============================================+
| SIMPLE      | table_c | NULL       | const  | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                    | PRIMARY                                    | 4       | const                  | 1     | 100.00   | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+-------------+---------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| SIMPLE      | table_b | NULL       | ref    | index_table_b_on_table_c_id_and_table_a_id,index_table_b_on_table_a_id                                                                                     | index_table_b_on_table_c_id_and_table_a_id | 5       | const                  | 23082 | 100.00   | Using where; Using index                     |
+-------------+---------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| SIMPLE      | table_a | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,index_table_a_on_ref,index_table_a_on_table_d_id_and_enabled,index_table_a_on_table_d_id,index_table_a_on_enabled,index_table_a_on_enabled_and_ref | PRIMARY                                    | 4       | app.table_b.table_a_id | 1     | 5.00     | Using where                                  |
+-------------+---------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

To my eyes, it looks like it's correctly using indices?

---

```sql
SELECT
  `table_a`.`id`
, `table_a`.`table_e_id`
, `table_a`.`table_b_id`
, `table_a`.`col_1`
, `table_a`.`col_2`
, `table_a`.`col_3`
, `table_a`.`price`
, `table_a`.`rrp`
, `table_a`.`col_4`
, `table_a`.`col_5`
, `table_a`.`col_6`
, `table_a`.`col_7`
, `table_a`.`col_8`
, `table_a`.`col_9`
, `table_a`.`col_10`
, table_d.id AS _table_d_id
FROM `table_a`
INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.table_b_id = table_b.id
INNER JOIN table_c ON table_b.id = table_c.table_b_id
INNER JOIN table_d ON table_d.id = table_c.table_d_id
INNER JOIN table_e ON table_b.table_e_id = table_e.id
WHERE `table_a`.`enabled` = TRUE
AND `table_a`.`published` = TRUE
AND (table_f_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
AND (table_b.enabled = TRUE)
AND (table_e.enabled = TRUE)
AND (
  (table_d.id = 1 AND price <= 828.09)
  OR (table_d.id = 2 AND price <= 1661.17)
  OR (table_d.id = 3 AND price <= 2494.26)
)
AND (1 = 1)
AND (1 = 1)
ORDER BY rrp desc
LIMIT 48 OFFSET 0;
```

This query took around 11 seconds to return 48 rows. Running this query now when the system isn't under load, it takes ~100ms. Below is the explain plan

```
+----+-------------+---------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                           | key                         | key_len | ref                                | rows | filtered | Extra                                                               |
+====+=============+=========+============+========+=========================================================================================================+=============================+=========+====================================+======+==========+=====================================================================+
| 1  |             | table_c |            | range  | index_table_c_on_table_d_id,index_table_c_on_table_b_id                                                 | index_table_c_on_table_d_id | 5       |                                    | 412  | 100.00   | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | table_d |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                 | PRIMARY                     | 4       | app.table_c.table_d_id             | 1    | 100.00   | Using index                                                         |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | table_b |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY,index_table_b_on_table_e_id_and_enabled                                                         | PRIMARY                     | 4       | app.table_c.table_b_id             | 1    | 10.00    | Using where                                                         |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | table_e |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY,index_table_e_on_enabled                                                                        | PRIMARY                     | 4       | app.table_b.table_e_id             | 1    | 88.24    | Using where                                                         |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | table_a |            | ref    | index_table_a_on_price,table_a_table_b_id_price,index_table_a_on_table_f_id,index_table_a_on_table_b_id | table_a_table_b_id_price    | 9       | const,const,app.table_c.table_b_id | 46   | 27.99    | Using index condition; Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: High CPU -- That means lack of an adequate index and/or need to reformulate queries.  Come back with slowlog info, as described here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: @RickJames We've got slow query log enabled and it filled with hundreds of queries during that time since essentially everything was taking too long. I'll edit the question to include some of them, but some of the worst offenders are using a `like` condition in the where clause, something which I've read is bad with the adaptive hash index (another reason I've looked at that)

Comment: How big is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  RAM?

Comment: Does RDS have setting for innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts and innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions?  If so, what are they set to.

Comment: @RickJames the machines have 16GB of RAM. `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is set to 3/4 of that (so 12GB). `innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts` is set to engine default which I believe is 8. There isn't one for `innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions` though i thought the `parts` one was partitions?

Answer (score 3):

The **first query** might start with table_a or it might start with table_c.  Here are the indexes to facilitate both query plans, thereby letting the Optimizer pick which seems better based on the data:

```
table_a:  -- I assume you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`?
table_a:  INDEX(enabled, table_d_id, ref,   -- in any order, then
                name)    -- last
table_b:  INDEX(product_id, brochure_id)  -- see link below
table_b:  INDEX(brochure_id, product_id)
table_c:  -- I assume you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`?
```

Since the only references to table_c are

```
INNER JOIN `table_c` ON `table_b`.`brochure_id` = `table_c`.`id`
WHERE `table_c`.`id` = 215
```

you may as well replace them with just

```
WHERE `table_b`.`brochure_id` = 215
```

Is table_b a many-to-many mapping table.  It is common for them to be inefficiently indexed.  See my guidelines:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

For the **Second query**, here are some things to get started with (in addition to the many:many advice, above):

```
a:  INDEX(enabled, published,   -- in either order, then
          table_f_id)   -- last
```

**EXPLAINs**

Here is a partial attempt at explaining the `EXPLAINs` that you have:

- `Using temporary; Using filesort` - At one (or possibly more) step of the execution something needs to be sorted, usually because of `ORDER BY`.  `GROUP BY x ORDER BY w` *may* lead to multiple sorts; `EXPLAIN` does not indicate that, but `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` does.  "Filesort" does not necessarily indicate that the disk is involved.
- `Using index` - The index was a "covering index", meaning that *all* the columns used *anywhere* in the query were found in a single `INDEX`.  This is usually beneficial for performance but is rarely a goal to start with.
- `key_len = 4` - probably a 4-byte `INT NOT NULL` (signed or unsigned); `=5` probably means `INT NULL`.  Consider making it `NOT NULL`.  (This is a minor issue.)
- The `Rows` column - Multiply the numbers in that column together to get a very crude estimate of work to perform the query.  This is *sometimes* useful in comparing two Explains.
- `Rows=1` - May indicate a unique key, hence a very efficient `JOIN`.
- `Rows = big number` - The table may have a lousy index.
- `JOINs` are usually done via "NLJ" (Nested Loop Join) - read one table, reaching into the next table one row at a time.
- The first row - The `table` in the first row is likely to be the one with the best `WHEREs`.  If not, perhaps you need a better index -- often a composite index.

Comment: Interesting read on the many:many mapping table thank you! `table_b` in the first query is one so will definitely give that a go. Do you have any good resources on how to fully interpret an explain plan by any chance?

Comment: And also what are you thoughts on the adaptive hash index, or do you think that's more of a red herring here?

Comment: @PaReeOhNos - `EXPLAIN` -- I wish I did, but I have not found a good one.  I'll be happy to elaborate on specific examples.  Note that `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` gives more detail and sometimes more clarity.  "Operator trace" is sometimes useful.

Comment: @PaReeOhNos - Unfortunately, `EXPLAIN` says only what is going on in the _current_ query plan; it fails to answer important questions like "what index would be best?".  The rest of my link makes an attempt at answering that question.

Comment: @PaReeOhNos - I spelled out some of the useful info in our `EXPLAINs`.

Comment: that's great thank you, helps a lot!